# SQL Server add 1 to counter based on result of case when

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

can anyone tell me if the code i have added should work?
It is giving me syntax errors and I don't know why.

The issue
The ticket numbers are sequential but occasionally there will be a large break of a few million numbers. The server cant calculate all few million rows as missing so I want to set a limit of say 50 missing before the code steps to the next cursor.

SAMPLE DATA SET

[image]

MORE CODE ADDED TO GIVE CONTEXT OF ISSUE.

```
DECLARE DB_CURSOR CURSOR FOR 

SELECT PCC
FROM 
#PCC_TEMP


OPEN DB_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM DB_CURSOR INTO
@NAME

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

;WITH Missing (missnum, maxid)
AS
(
 SELECT (select min(Ticket_no) from #Temp where PCC = @name) AS missnum, (select max(Ticket_no) from #Temp where PCC = @name)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT missnum + 1, maxid FROM Missing
 WHERE missnum < maxid

)

SELECT missnum as [Ticket],
case when(tt.Ticket_no is NULL) then '' else tt.routing_info END as [Routing],
case when(tt.Ticket_no is NULL) then '' else tt.trip END as [Trip],
case when(tt.Ticket_no is NULL) then '' else tt.PNR END as [PNR],
case when(tt.Ticket_no is NULL) then '' else tt.PCC END as [PCC],
case when(tt.Ticket_no is NULL) then 'Missing' else 'Present' END as [Status],
case when(tt.Ticket_no is NULL) then     SET @Missing_Counter = @Missing_Counter +1 END

FROM Missing
LEFT OUTER JOIN #Temp tt on tt.Ticket_no = Missing.missnum
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0); 


FETCH NEXT FROM DB_CURSOR INTO
@NAME

END

CLOSE DB_CURSOR

DEALLOCATE DB_CURSOR

DROP TABLE #Temp

DROP TABLE #PCC_TEMP
```

Cheers

Dave

Comment: Can you give more of your SQL?

Comment: added more code thanks

Comment: Your problem is you're trying to set inside your select.

Comment: ok so where is best to set considering it will need to run on each row

Comment: Looks like this is the final select in a recursive-cte, can you post the entire cte? Also, what is the ultimate goal of the missing counter (do you need a running total, or a total count)?

Comment: posted entire cursor routine above. Obviously minus declares and select into temp tables etc

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think what would help folks help you the most is adding some sample schema/data and the desired result. I believe you only need either the recursive-cte (preferred, as the set-based approach) or the cursor, not both. Can you also tag the question with what version of SQL Server you're on (08/12/14/16/etc.)?

Comment: There are multiple sequences running in the data so the cursor limits each pass to a single sequence. Inside the cursor, the recursive looks at the current sequence and then identifies all the present and missing numbers in order.

Comment: sample data image added above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server after 2008, you can just use `lag()` and `lead()`.  You can do:

```
select (ticket_number + 1) as first_missing,
       (next_ticket_number - 1) as last_missing,
       (next_ticket_number - ticket_number - 1) as num_missing
from (select t.*, lead(ticket_number) over (order by ticket_number) as next_ticket_number
      from #Temp t
     ) t
where next_ticket_number <> ticket_number + 1;
```

Forget about your syntax error.  The code would probably be really inefficient anyway.  Also, I don't see why you would want a cursor for this.  Use set-based methods when you can.

In earlier versions, you can do this as:

```
select (ticket_number + 1) as first_missing,
       (next_ticket_number - 1) as last_missing,
       (next_ticket_number - ticket_number - 1) as num_missing
from (select t.*, t2.ticket_number as next_ticket_number
      from #Temp t cross apply
           (select top (1) t2.ticket_number
            from #temp t2
            where t2.ticket_number > t.ticket_number
            order by t2.ticket_number asc
           ) t2
     ) t
where next_ticket_number <> ticket_number + 1;
```

Although this is less efficient than `lead()`, it can make use of an index on `ticket_number()`.

Comment: I am using 2008 R2 not sure Lag and Lead are even an option for me sadly.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is to count the null ticket numbers then why not count the null ticket numbers?

```
SELECT @Missing_Counter = COUNT(1) 
FROM {Table}
WHERE Ticket_no is NULL
```

Comment: I could have 3 million nulls in a row whixh is too process heavy. I want to set a limit of say 50 nulls and then skip to the next step.